# Remix/Android wallet app?

Tags: solidity, remix

Is it possible to create an ethereum smart contract using remix from the browser of your android device and then linking it to your android ether wallet app without using a PC anywhere along the token creation process?

Comment: You can use MyEtherWallet in Firefox Android / iOS with MetaMask.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on your use-case?